# Using a Lua Script to send inputs to BizHawk

Tags: lua, emulation

I've tried using joypad.set(Inputs), but that doesn't seem to do anything. Also joypad.write(Inputs) doesn't even work. I'm stuck in a corner, and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far and the errors you're getting (if any)?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/T9QJRxPG Iknow the code is a mess, but it's what works for me. The error code that I'm getting is ":59: attempt to call field 'write' (a nil value)." (that's when it's not commented out) I've tried both .set and .write, but to no avail.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, according to [this](http://tasvideos.org/Bizhawk/LuaFunctions.html) `joypad.write` is not supported for Bizhawk.

Comment: My apologies for being so near sighted, but it seems that I have to put P1 before any input.

Answer (score 3):

This example works for when emulating a GBA. It will make the emulator press right every frame

```
input = {}

input['A'] = false
input['B'] = false
input['Down'] = false
input['L'] = false
input['Left'] = false
input['Power'] = false
input['R'] = false
input['Right'] = true
input['Select'] = false
input['Start'] = false
input['Up'] = false

while true do 
    joypad.set(input) 
    emu.frameadvance()
end
```

---

depending what you emulating this also might be useful

```
input['P1 A'] = false
```